# How to fix problem with running my first ARCore App under Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I am trying to create my first ARCore App on Unity 3D. I used example scene and my own scene, both. I set up all options as shown in instructions (about quick start with ARCore).
When I connect my phone (Samsung A30 (which is support ARCore and has Services for AR App installed) and push Play button in Unity, then I see that Services for AR run at my phone and I see in player image from my phone's camera. And the test scene works good.
But when I run 'Run and Build', I has no errors and I see that my App successfully installed on my phone. But when I run it, I see just Unity3D logo and my App crashes (or, may be not, because I see that it in on runed applications list). And I searched how can I solve this problem and did not find any answer.
Can anybody, please, help me?

I used all instructions from the web, and goes step-by-step

I am expecting to see built and runed App on my phone with AR

Comment: Try to uncheck the "Android TV Compatibility" from Player settings and try again.